# Does vote(up/down) in MSEmeta affect reputation in MSE or the converse.

Tags: support, reputation, meta, meta-reputation

Does the vote up and vote down in ***MSEmeta*** affect the reputation in ***MSE*** or the converse. Also why is there a difference between the **reputation** of ***MSEmeta*** and ***MSE***. They are fairly close in my case, just wondering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Voting on meta.math.SE does **not** affect reputation anywhere.

(However, the badges you gain on meta.math.SE are **separate** from your badges on math.SE.)

Your meta.math.SE reputation is a copy of your math.SE reputation, though sometimes it takes a few hours to update to the latest value. This is how all meta.____.SE sites work, **except** for meta.stackoverflow.

[See this meta.stackoverflow post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91336/161783).

Comment: Ah, Zev. You're faster than I am.

Comment: Thank you for this.

Answer (score 3):

Meta has no impact on your main reputation. Instead, your meta rep is exactly your main rep, with any discrepancy caused only by a small latency between rep changes on main being updated to your meta account.

Comment: Thank you for this.