# Do I gain or lose reputation based on the meta website?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, meta

Do upvotes and downvotes affect my reputation in the Mathematics Stack exchange site from this Mathematics Meta website? Also do comments or anything that I do on the meta allow me to earn badges or privileges on the real http://math.stackexchange.com? Any help would be truly greatly appreciated. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: The answer is NO to all your question.

Comment: @Surb That is really sad...

Comment: See also: [Does vote(up/down) in MSEmeta affect reputation in MSE or the converse.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10765/does-voteup-down-in-msemeta-affect-reputation-in-mse-or-the-converse)

Comment: @MartinSleziak OK Thx, umm how do I vote up your comment as helpful?

Comment: @anonymous You need to get to 15 reputation points before you can upvote: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up More details here: [How does comment voting and flagging work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Ok, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as your questions about badges is concerned, you do not get badges on main for your activity on meta. There are two exceptions:

- [Quorum badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/78/quorum): One post with score of 2 on meta.
- [Convention badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/79/convention): 10 posts with score of 2 on meta.

However, you can earn [badges on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges). (You have probably noticed that as you have already earned some meta-badges.)

---

Upvotes/downvotes on meta do not influence your reputation on the main site. See also here:

- [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) in help
- [Does vote(up/down) in MSEmeta affect reputation in MSE or the converse.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10765/does-voteup-down-in-msemeta-affect-reputation-in-mse-or-the-converse)
- [Why don't Meta upvotes count?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256625/why-dont-meta-upvotes-count)
- [Rep Gain/Lose on Per-Site Metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247186/rep-gain-lose-on-per-site-metas)
- [How does reputation between the main site and its meta work on SE 2.0?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56172/how-does-reputation-between-the-main-site-and-its-meta-work-on-se-2-0)

Comment: Ok thx cool, that really answered my question...I guess I'll be getting a Quorum badge soon...if I could upvote I really would.